# Assigning a false value to an <a> tag

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a fieldrenderer that when a value is inputted, the field shows up, but when there is no value, the field does not. This part of the code works. My issue is that the fieldrenderer is wrapped in a "a href" tag and thus when the field is null, the css still shows up on the page that was given to the "a href" tag. Is there a way to make the  tag not visible as well as the field?

```
   <div>
       <a href="#" class="test" id="tester" runat="server">
       <sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Value" runat="server" ID="thelist" Item="<%# thelistID %>" /></a>
   </div>
```

backend:

```
            FieldRenderer thelistID = (FieldRenderer)e.Item.FindControl("thelistID");
            HtmlAnchor test = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("tester");
            if (AddToList == null)
            {
                thelistID.Visible = false;
                test.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                thelistID.Item = AddToList;
            }
```

Comment: So to clarify are you saying that in the rendered HTML (ie when you view source on the browser) that the `<a>` tag is still present but without any content? If so then it would seem that you're findControl is not returning the right thing or that something else is setting it to visible after this point. You should be able to determine which via debugging. I'm not sure there is much more that we can tell you though based on what you've given us (and I'm not sure what else to ask for that might give us more clues).

Answer (score 0):

create another CSS class (e.g.: Invisible_HREF), and in your if statement above, set the CSS class on the `HtmlAnchor` to the invisible class.

Comment: that is what the test.visible = false is for, but it doesn't recognize it. I tried to do a test.style.display('none'), but that didn't work.

Comment: that's not what visible is for... visible will hide the control, but if it has a CSS class, it will still show the CSS stuff in it. It would be good to see what your CSS class is for "test" right now, as well as the resulting "View Source" from the browser when you set it to visible=false

Comment: test {font-size:17px; line-height:27px; color:#fff; background:#f58426; display:inline-block; padding:0 10px; border-radius:5px; border:#f58426 1px solid;}

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv: I think you rae confusing CSS visible with the ASP.NET meaning of visible. The latter should prevent the item from being rendered to the browser.

Comment: it shows a portion of the border and that's it when the value=null

Comment: @Chris correct, which is why i want to see what the "View Source" looks like when he sets it to visible=false... it simply shouldn't show up at all, and yet he says it does, which means it's more complex than just a CSS issue. Keith please post the View Source in your original question...

Comment: I did a view page source and there isn't anything that shows up in the div. I've done a clear cache and the problem is on the page but not in the view page soure code

Comment: I did this as well test.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none"); but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
 <a href="#" class="test" id="tester" runat="server" visible='<%# isVisible %>'> 
 <sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Value" runat="server" ID="thelist" Item="<%# thelistID %>" /></a>
</div>

 FieldRenderer thelistID = (FieldRenderer)e.Item.FindControl("thelistID");
        HtmlAnchor test = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("tester");

        if (AddToList == null || AddToList.Count == 0)
        {
           isVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isVisible = true;
            thelistID.Item = AddToList;
        }
```